# How do I approach this complex integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to compute the following

$$\oint_{\delta D(0,1)} \frac{e^{\alpha z}}{2z^2-5z+2}dz.$$

**My attempt:**

\begin{align*}
\oint_{\delta D(0,1)} \frac{e^{\alpha z}}{2z^2-5z+2}dz &=\oint_{\delta D(0,1)} \frac{e^{\alpha z}}{(z-2)(2z-1)}dz \\
&= \frac{1}{3}\left( \oint_{\delta D(0,1)} \frac{e^{\alpha z}}{z-2}dz - \oint_{\delta D(0,1)}\frac{e^{\alpha z}}{z-\frac{1}{2}}dz \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \left(\oint_{\delta D(0,1)} \frac{e^{\alpha z}}{z-2} dz -2\pi i e^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \right)
\end{align*}

where the later integral was computed through Caychy's Integral Formula.

Here is where I am stuck, I don't know how to integrate $\oint_{\delta D(0,1)} \frac{e^{\alpha z}}{z-2}dz$. Any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact
$$\oint_{\delta D(0,1)} \frac{e^{\alpha z}}{z-2}dz=0$$
since $\frac{e^{\alpha z}}{z-2}$ is analytic in $\bar{D}(0,1)$.